# I have two forms, one has student data and other one has date and attendance status

Tags: javascript, arrays

[student data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAWkV.png) [attendance when clicking the attendance button on the first data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uMKq.png) [attendance when clicking the attendance button on the first data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vdwT.png)
I have to make it such a way that when I click on a particular data, only that id's attendance data should come up.

Here is how I stored my data for the attendance form:

```
function saveatt() {
  //get data from localstorage and store to attendancesheet array
  //we must to use JSON.parse, because data as string, we need convert to array
  attendancesheet = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stdlist")) ?? [];

  //get last array to get last id
  //and store it into variable id
  var id;
  attendancesheet.length != 0
    ? attendancesheet.findLast((item) => (id = item.id))
    : (id = 0);

  if (document.getElementById("id").value) {
    //edit attendancesheet array based on value
    var att=[];
    
   

    var Present = document.getElementById("Present");
    if(Present.checked){
        att.push(Present.value)
    }
    var Absent = document.getElementById("Absent");
    if(Absent.checked){
        att.push(Absent.value)
    }

   
    attendancesheet.forEach((value) => {
      if (document.getElementById("id").value == value.id) {
          (value.date = document.getElementById("date").value),
          (value.attendance = att)
      }
    });
```

And I have done the same for student data. Just the array is named contactlist instead of attendancesheet.

```
    function studentData() {
    studenttable.innerHTML = ``;
    //get data from localstorage and store to attendancesheet array
    //we must to use JSON.parse, because data as string, we need convert to array
    attendancesheet = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stdlist")) ?? [];
  
    //looping data and show data in table
    attendancesheet.forEach(function (value, i) {
      var table = document.getElementById("studenttable");
  
      studenttable.innerHTML += `
              <tr>
                  <td>${i + 1}</td>
                  <td>${value.date}
                  <td>${value.attendance}</td>
          
                  <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="findreport(${
                        value.id
                      })">
                          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                      </button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="removeatt(${
                        value.id
                      })">
                          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                      </button>
                  </td>
              </tr>`
                  })
              }

    function findreport(id){
    //get data from localstorage and store to attendancesheet array
    //we must to use JSON.parse, because data as string, we need convert to array
  
    attendancesheet = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('stdlist')) ?? []

    attendancesheet.forEach(function (value){
        if(value.id == id){
           document.getElementById('id').value = value.id,
           document.getElementById('date').value = value.date
        //    document.getElementById('attendance').value = value.attendance

        }
    })
}

   function removeatt(id){
    //get data from localstorage and store to attendancesheet array
    //we must to use JSON.parse, because data as string, we need convert to array
    attendancesheet = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('stdlist')) ?? []

    attendancesheet = attendancesheet.filter(function(value){ 
        return value.id != id; 
    });

    // save array into localstorage
    localStorage.setItem('stdlist', JSON.stringify(attendancesheet))

    //get data again
    studentData()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `when I click on a particular data, only that id's attendance data should come up.` ? Currently it is showing based on the clicked record only right.

Comment: nop,its showing the same for both the ids

Comment: I can only see the method to save attendance. Can you please put the code which is responsible to show the attendance

Comment: reset or update the array based on the clicked student id ? if you are getting the attendance data from an API, just pass id of student and then fetch

Comment: yes update based on the id clicked in the first table

Comment: Yes got it. Can you please show me how you are doing it currently so that i can help you out

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I updated the question with all the codes related to the attendance form,please check out

Comment: `studentData` is a method which is used to show the attendance on click of "attendance" button ? If Yes, Instead of looping whole `attendancesheet` array you should loop only the elements which contain the student id. For that from `attendancesheet`, just filtered out the array based on the passed student id.